# Proper way to have an access to one file inside every python script, without chaning the path to that file

Tags: python, path

Looking for a way to have an access to file inside every python script.
I have a below file-tree:

```
├──module
│   └──module
│        └──script.py
│        └──script2.py
│   └──module2
│        └──folder
│             └──script3.py
│   └──file.csv
```

and now i would like to have an option inside every .py file to use the same line to access file.csv
because right now i need to use different path for every .py. How do i do it?
So i don't need to think about path just use `pd.read_csv('file.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the absolute path to the file, you would need to add this to every script, but it would be the same in every file.

So this would be

```
file_path = r'C:\some\path\to\file.csv'
```

Comment: It's not what i am looking for.
that way if i move my repo or clone it somewhere else, I would need to change it every time.